# Return Functions Don't work. Using pythagorean Theorem

Tags: c, debugging, robotics, nxt

```
#pragma config(Motor,  port1,           RightsideB,    tmotorVex393_HBridge, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  port2,           RightsideF,    tmotorVex393_MC29, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  port9,           LefttsideF,    tmotorVex393_MC29, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  port10,          LeftsideB,     tmotorVex393_HBridge, openLoop)
//*!!Code automatically generated by 'ROBOTC' configuration wizard             !!*//

float xdiff, ydiff, firstpart, secondpart, firstpart2, secondpart2, total, lengthformula;
float getdistance(int x1, int x2,int y1, int y2){
    return x1;
    return x2;
    return y1;
    return y2;

    xdiff = x2 - x1;
    ydiff = y2 - y1;

    firstpart = (xdiff);
    return firstpart;
    secondpart = (ydiff);
    firstpart2 = pow(xdiff,2);
    secondpart2 = pow(ydiff, 2);

    total = firstpart2 + secondpart2;
    lengthformula = sqrt(total);
    return lengthformula;
}

task main()
{
    getdistance(0, 4, 0, 1);
    while (true){
        motor[RightsideB]= vexRT[Ch2];
        motor[RightsideF] = vexRT[Ch2];
        motor[LeftsideB]= vexRT[Ch3]; 
        motor[LefttsideF]= vexRT[Ch3];

    }

}
```

This program will run without errors, but when i run it and open debugger, the variables dont work. I have programmed in smallbasic and i know this works on it. im converting it to robot-c

Comment: If you have `return` in the middle of a function, the rest of the function doesn't execute.

Comment: You're not assigning the return value to anything in `main()`.

Comment: So where should the return functions go? and how do i assign a return in the main(0 i tried to for it for getdistance but i got major errors.

Comment: recall that the getdistance function is a void so i cant put return getdistance(0,4,0,1)

Comment: `getdistance` is not a void function, it's `float getdistance(...)`

Comment: I can't figure out what you're doing. Why are you trying to return twice in the function?

Comment: It seems like you just don't understand what `return x1` is for. I think it's time for you to go back to your textbook and learn the basics.

Comment: yes it s a float but when i run return getdistance(...) its states that its a void function. so that makes it a void function by defalt.

Comment: That's because `main()` is a void function. Why would you want to return the distance from `main()`?

Comment: ok i was returning to many function and im learning robotc for my team. i know i shouldn't be programmer but im pretty boss at smallbasic, so i do understand the fundamentals of programming. HTml, css, smallbasic, and some python is what i know.

Comment: `return` in C is similar to BASIC and Python.

Comment: in small basic there is no return. its just assign a variable and thats it. ex.

sub hello
sign = 10
endsub

textwindow.writeline(sign) 'prints 10'

Comment: If you want help with this program, you need to explain what it's supposed to do. What do you want to do with the distance that you've calculated?

Comment: im returning distance because im doing coordinates for where the robot has to go. so im using distance formula, and law of sins and arclength formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all the `return` statements in `getdistance`, except `return lengthformula` at the end. `return` causes the function to stop running, and immediately return the value you specify, so the rest of the function never runs and the distance never gets calculated.

In `main()`, you need to assign the result to a variable:

```
task main() {
    float distance = getdistance(0, 4, 0, 1);
    ...
}
```

Then you can use `distance` for whatever you need.

Comment: I would be able to use that as a global yes?

Comment: In my answer it's a local variable. You could declare it globally instead, and then just assign `distance = getdistance(0. 4, 0, 1)`.

Comment: and i would be able to see the value by going to the debugger? btw thanks for the help. i was so lost. our lead programmer had no clue. he has a lot more experienc ebut hes never used that.

Comment: Yes, you can see the values of all variables in the debugger.